# Http response better practice

Tags: json, http

I'm developing a web application and would like to know how (what is the best practice) should the server respond to the client when he wants to log in.

The client provides his credentials in a form (e.g. username,password) and issues a POST request to a server. The content transferred between the client and server is always JSON formatted (`Content-Type: application/json`).

This is how my server responds to the client:

- Credentials are wrong. The server responds `{"status":"error","message":"Credentials are incorrect."}`.
- Credentials are correct and the client is not logged in. The server responds `{"status":"ok","message":"Log in success."}`
- Credentials are correct and the client is logged in. The server responds `{"status":"ok","message":"User is already logged in."}`

Is my implementation considered bad practice? Should the server just respond with just a `Status:200` for the first two cases and a `Status:401` for the last one?

If the credentials are invalid? e.g a client issues a POST request to the server with with no post parameters? Should the response of the server then be 400?

Comment: IMHO, you'd be taking the HTTP metaphor too far. What happens when your app needs to return a very specific message where there's no HTTP code available, such as "credit exhausted" or "you've been banned for cheating".

Comment: The server will respond 200 with json content in those situations I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, If you are trying to create somekind of secure http based apis, you will need some kind of authentication in each call this may be some session key in querystring in every call or some cookie or use basic header to pass username/password in header for every request.

For your question you should return 401 Unauthorized status code with your message for 1st & 2nd case, for third return 200 OK status code. It should also return 404 unauthorized code for invalid post parameters? (no username)? etc,

Comment: What about when the client sends invalid post parameters? (no username)? Should the response status code then be 400?

Comment: Can you edit your answer so it could include the the case of invalid post parameters? I'll mark it as the accepted one.